# How does the selective "Comments have been moved to chat" work here? (Why are some comments not moved to chat?)

Tags: discussion

On other Stackexchange sites, usually when a moderator performs the "Comments have been moved to chat" action, she moves **all** of the comments (under a particular Q or A) to chat.

Here though, it seems that at least one moderator routinely chooses to move some but not all comments to chat.

---

For example, at [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/184990) to the question "Does any beach in Sentosa Island in Singapore allow swimming after 7pm?", Willeke chose not to move to chat this comment:

> in Singapore, you should assume all rules are implemented at all times

I fail to see how this particular comment "request[s] clarification or suggest[s] improvements". As such, I fail to see why this particular comment was not also moved to chat.

---

How does the selective move to chat here work?

Are there any objective criteria by which moderators here may choose not to move to chat particular comments?

Or is it entirely a matter of the moderators liking some comments more than others and so choosing not to move those comments they like?

Comment: Just a quick correction: Excluding the big-3, things work pretty much the same way as here on most SE sites. Highly upvoted comments that are relevant tend to be allowed to persist.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any objective criteria by which moderators here may choose not to move to chat particular comments?

Highly upvoted and highly relevant comments are usually left in place when moving comments to chat - but this isn't formally defined anywhere, as it's up to each mod to decide what to do.

> Or is it entirely a matter of the moderators liking some comments more than others and so choosing not to move those comments they like?

Comments are second-class citizens on StackExchange and one should assume that any comment may be deleted at any time. So, yes, this is more or less a matter of moderator preference, though users can also flag comments for mod review if they find them objectionable.

Comment: I see. So I guess I can just love it or leave it. I'll choose the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Usually all the comments are moved to the chatroom but not all are deleted from the question or answer.

Only when I get a warning that some comments can not be moved I delete those before moving the lot, happens rarely. If highly upvoted or highly relevant I usually undelete after moving the rest, mostly I do not.

It is a bit of a site tradition.

When the comments have been moved I am rather strict on not leaving any comments under the 'moved' message, in that case they were warned.
If there is a continued discussion I also lock the comments, mostly for a week but it can be permanent.

And no, it is not comments I like, it is highly upvotes comments and sometimes a lower upvoted one that shows the opposite point of view.